# Jquery is not able to load mo.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just learned about mo.js and have started using it but little bit confused about this.
I have included the mo.js CDN in my code

```
var burst=new mojs.Burst({      
       radius:{0:20},  
       count:10,  
       children:{  
         shape:'circle',  
         radius:5,  
         opacity:{1:0},  
         fill:['green','yellow','pink'],  
         duration:3000  
       }  
     });
```

but it still gives the error mojs is not defined. any help is appreciable.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without *a clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If `mojs` is not defined, then you need to include an excerpt at least of where you are including the CDN script, its a bit pointless posting an example of its usage.  Also, note your browser version and make sure its supported, and check and post any console messages.

Comment: Sorry guys, it is noobs mistake I have included it on wrong place. But now I am facing new problem it works only after refreshing the page. When we first land on the page it is not working.